# Convert PHP source to Java source?

Tags: java, php, converters

I have a class written in PHP which I use to communicate with my website databases. I am also writing a Java application which will communicate with a database too. I was wondering if it was possible to use the same structure but convert it to java and are there any issues I would need to consider if I do this. Here is my php class...

```
<?php

class Database {

    private static $instance = null;
    private $connection;
    private $selected_database;
    private $last_query;

    public static function getInstance() {
        if (self::$instance != null) {
            return self::$instance;
        } else {
            return new self;
        }
    }

    function __construct() {
        $this->open_connection();
    }

    private function open_connection() {
        $this->connection = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
        if (!$this->connection) {
            die('Database connection failed: ' . mysql_error());
        } else {
            $this->selected_database = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $this->connection);
            if (!$this->selected_database) {
                die('Database selection failed: ' . mysql_error());
            }
        }
    }

    private function close_connection() {
        if (isset($this->connection)) {
            mysql_close($this->connection);
            unset($this->connection);
        }
    }

    public function query($sql) {
        $this->last_query = $sql;
        $result = mysql_query($sql, $this->connection);
        $this->confirm_query($result);
        return $result;
    }

    private function confirm_query($result) {
        if (!$result) {
            die('Database query failed: ' . mysql_error() . '<br>Last SQL query: ' . $this->last_query);
        }
    }

    public function escape_value($string) {
        return mysql_real_escape_string($string);
    }

    public function fetch_array($result) {
        return mysql_fetch_array($result);
    }

    public function fetch_assoc($result) {
        return mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    }

    public function num_rows($result) {
        return mysql_num_rows($result);
    }

    public function insert_id() {
        return mysql_insert_id($this->connection);
    }

    public function affected_rows() {
        return mysql_affected_rows($this->connection);
    }

    public function get_fields_from($table_name) {
        $result = $this->query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM `{$this->escape_value($table_name)}`");
        $fields = array();
        while ($row = $this->fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $fields[] = $row['Field'];
        }
        return $fields;
    }

}

?>
```

Comment: if determined, yes you can convert program from any language to other, and of course you must write code yourselves!!

Comment: And I don't want anyone to write code for me, where's the fun in that? I just wanted to know anything I should watch out for while converting this code

Comment: If I keep getting down votes for every question I post just because of the way I reacted to something last week, then I will stop asking questions here. I am building a online poker site, would you really want to miss out on the chance to see some of that code?

Comment: @JohnPringle: We don't really care about seeing your code.

Comment: @duskwuff, Then obviously my question wasn't directed at you. And you seem to believe you have the ability to answer for others. And thanks for the extra downvote :) Semantics, my dear watson

Comment: @JohnPringle: No, really. Getting "the chance to see some of that code" isn't some sort of treat for us. Come back when you have a real, specific problem you're running into, not just a nebulous question about what issues you might encounter in the future.

Comment: Why doesn't someone tell me what is wrong with my question? All I seem to get is down-voted with no explanation as to why. I'm new to this site and this is the kind of attitude you all have towards me ever since my first question. I regret even coming here. The popularity of this site is misleading, you're all just a bunch of dicks who think every one must ask their questions in a specific way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No you can create a class in Java, which has a structure, that is nearly like the one above.

`or die()` is like throwing an `Exception`. You should be aware, that there are different ways of returning data from a database in Java and PHP. PHP often uses arrays or assoc-arrays. In Java you will get a "pointer" to the result. 
You must decide, if you want to transfer the data to an array, because of the memory consumption.